# Интерфейс CharSequence и его методы

Tags: java

Имеем `interface CharSequence`. Данный интерфейс содержит в себе следующие методы:

```
charAt(int index);
lenght();
subSequence(int start, int end);
toString();
```

Вопрос следующий: Возможно ли в IDEA при создании упомянутого интерфейса не писать его методы в ручную, а вызвать хоткеями? Как, например через alt + insert можно быстро вызвать геттеры и сеттеры, либо конструкторы класса.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вряд ли. Данный интерфейс подразумевает ручное создание какой-то новой реализации для данного интерфейса. Вдруг Вы создадите свою реализацию, которая вмещает в себя числовые значения символов и сортируется в порядке хэш-кодов. Тогда *IDEA* просто не сможет догадаться, что же там такое.

По умолчанию она может генерировать только пустые методы, которые возвращают `null`, 0 и `false`, в зависимости от возвращаемого типа. Михаил описал данный пункт более подробно.